# Site Collection Vs Hubsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, site-collection, hub-site

How do you relate Site Collections with the new Hub sites?

Are they fundamentally different or just an old wine in a new mug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the `Hub site` is considered a **top-level** site collection for other site collections to serves the **flat** structure, unlike the old Site collection and its subsites structure!

the `Hub site` has the below characteristics

- Created from a team or communication template,
- Only created by admin,
- Only available in SharePoint online.
- Preferred to use with the modern site experience.
- It's only allowed to create 100 hub sites in your organization.
- You can search for all sites content below the site hub.
- Easy navigation for all sites below site hub.
- Easy to show and roll-up content from all sites to the main hub.
- No permission inheritance from the hub to other sites, every site has its independent permission settings

---

**So** it's fundamentally different from the normal site collection!

## **Hub Site**

[image]

## **Site Collection**

[image]

You can read more about How the Hub site is working at [Planning your SharePoint hub sites.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fplanning-your-sharepoint-hub-sites-4e95dcd8-7e79-4732-aa9b-2f351031b4c2)